# Incomplete php cloud transfer and copy

Tags: php, wordpress

I want transfer a file between two wordpress hostings and i use this code:

```
<?php
copy("https://a.com/b.zip", "b.zip");
?>
```

the file is about 500mb , but everytime it will incomplete and just upload few percentages of the file , from 10 to 200 mb . i use namecheap wordpress hosting .

- php 7.4
- Maximum Upload Limit set by WordPress = 1gb
- PHP Limit Time = 3600
- WordPress Upload Directory Writable Permission = writable

and i hadn't any problem to upload these file from my local computer, i tried multcloud but it was unsuccessful too. what should i do?

Comment: chunk down them in 2-3 zips of smaller sizes and try to do

Comment: i cant , its .wpress and i cant chunk down

Answer (score 0):

Seems like time and speed limit to me.

So first thing to add is `ignore_user_abort(true);` before `copy` to avoid aborting script on client timeout. Increase time limit if possible.

Another options to consider is breaking file into smaller chunks or using something more advanced to download, like curl based client able to resume unfinished download (i.e. see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ndunks/778c7efad0956e0f99deae73c52e718f))

Copied gist here

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
$url    = "http://web.shit/backup.zip";

$ch = curl_init($url);
$to_file    = 'web.zip';
$opt    = array();
if(is_file($to_file))
{
    $sz = filesize($to_file);
    $opt[CURLOPT_RANGE] = $sz . "-";
    
}
$opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
$opt[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = true;
$opt[CURLOPT_FILE]  = fopen($to_file, 'a');
$opt[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36';
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt);
curl_exec($ch);
$grab_info  = curl_getinfo($ch);
fclose($opt[CURLOPT_FILE]);

print_r($grab_info);
```

Comment: Thank you,  but i doesn't work, i tried the your code and it just create a 0 byte file , and used ignore_user_abort(true); and set time limite , and my main issue is remain , it just copy few mb of it

Comment: Any error? Like curl extension is not installed? Because I've tried it and it works. Doesn't follow redirects though...

Comment: Try to show errors. On shared hostings it sometimes not easy to find them in logs. Especially if it's infected Wordpress.

//just for debugging issues
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Array ( [url] => http://exaple.com/file.wpress [content_type] => [http_code] => 301 [header_size] => 132 [request_size] => 220 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.025726 [namelookup_time] => 0.023578 [connect_time] => 0.024956 [pretransfer_time] => 0.025091 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0.025653 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => https://example.com/file.wpress [primary_ip] => 1.2.3.XMR58196

Comment: [http_version] => 2 [protocol] => 1 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => HTTP [appconnect_time_us] => 0 [connect_time_us] => 24956 [namelookup_time_us] => 23578 [pretransfer_time_us] => 25091 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 25653 [total_time_us] => 25726 )

Comment: [http_code] => 301 - that means redirect, which is not followed, hence 0 bytes result. Add this line: $opt[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = true; I've updated code in my answer.

Comment: i use the new code and i get the same result

Comment: Should be something different... But it looks like redirect itself is broken - redirects to the same URL if I read it right - in both cases "https://example.com/file.wpress" In that case redirect count reaches limit and curl stops. UPD: Oh, I see, first link http and redirect to https. What if use right link from the start?

Comment: Array ( [url] => https://example.com/file.wpress [content_type] => application/octet-stream [http_code] => 206 [header_size] => 527 [request_size] => 235 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.34568 [namelookup_time] => 0.011936 [connect_time] => 0.012921 [pretransfer_time] => 0.030943 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 23444609 [speed_download] => 67955388 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 508477817 [upload_content_length] => 0  [starttransfer_time] => 0.050033 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 63.250.43.132

Comment: [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 1.2.3.4 [local_port] => 57084 [http_version] => 3 [protocol] => 2 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => HTTPS [appconnect_time_us] => 30721 [connect_time_us] => 12921 [namelookup_time_us] => 11936 [pretransfer_time_us] => 30943 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 50033 [total_time_us] => 345680 )

Comment: it'll download now, but not complete, i refresh the php code to download a bit and its go up, and when it gained to 120 it downloads few kb, and then stick in 127.98 mb from 484mb

Comment: Well, it works as intended I suppose... It's something external interferes now, like *download* limit by hosting (you don't expect site to download much on its own after all). You might already spent all that 1 GB limit (is it per day/week/month?). But check free space to be sure. Also be careful with refreshing, this code isn't safe for parallel execution.

Comment: I've downloaded 4+ GB file by this code without issues, just browser page timed out, but downloading process continued until done. So refreshing before that would trash downloaded data. There should be some file locking added for safety.